# Query Parse.com Date Column

Tags: date, parse-platform

I have a class called Events which contains a column called EventDate of type Date. In my query what format does the date need to be in to query successfully? The query succeeds, but always shows me 0 events. I have one event in my class which should match the criteria that has an EventDate value of Feb 14, 2014, 03:48. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("EventDate", new Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> events, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("Events", "Total Events:  " + events.size());
            } else {
                Log.d("Events", "Error:  " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Date should be correct. Does your query work if you comment out the "whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo"-statement?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue.  I was not aware that the date/time stored in my Parse class was stored in GMT time.  When I convert the current local time to GMT time and send that I am able to get my query results.

Comment: Can you please your sample code here, It will help other..

Thanks!